# Can't execute a .sql file - ERROR 1064 (42000)

Tags: sql, database, mariadb

I've got a .sql file with 16GB. It has a lot of data that I need, but I couldn't access those data because every time I try to put it into a db an error happen. I have no experience with mysql and probably I'm doing something wrong.
That's what I'm doing:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
> create database myData
> use myData
> commit
```

then

```
$ mysql -u root -p myData < data.sql
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'TRANSACTION' at line 1
```

But I don't know what's wrong in this file

```
$ head data.sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "cnpj_dados_cadastrais_pj" (
    "tipo_de_registro"  TEXT,
    "indicador" TEXT,
    "tipo_atualizacao"  TEXT,
    "cnpj"  TEXT,
    "identificador_matriz_filial"   TEXT,
    "razao_social"  TEXT,
    "nome_fantasia" TEXT,
    "situacao_cadastral"    TEXT,
```

My computer specifications:

```
$ uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 5.13.4-200.fc34.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jul 20 20:27:29 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.5.11-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

$ systemctl status mariadb.service
mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.5 database server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-07-28 08:16:50 -04; 1h 50min ago
       Docs: man:mariadbd(8)
             https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
   Main PID: 4746 (mariadbd)
     Status: "Taking your SQL requests now..."
      Tasks: 8 (limit: 14203)
     Memory: 17.1M
        CPU: 1.455s
     CGroup: /system.slice/mariadb.service
             └─4746 /usr/libexec/mariadbd --basedir=/usr
```

After accessing the data, I want to save it as a .db file or something like that to open it with Python Pandas.

---

Updates:
I ran sed -i '1 s/BEGIN TRANSACTION/START TRANSACTION/1' myFile.sql as Álvaro González suggested and I got another error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '"cnpj_dados_cadastrais_pj" (
    "tipo_de_registro"  TEXT,
    "indicador" TEXT,
    "t...' at line 1
```

Comment: I think it's either `START TRANSACTION` or `BEGIN`; you can't mix them: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/start-transaction/

Comment: I've got a new error now. 
```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '"cnpj_dados_cadastrais_pj" (
 "tipo_de_registro" TEXT,
 "indicador" TEXT,
 "t...' at line 1
```

Comment: Using double quotes for identifiers is not the default setting, you need to enable [ANSI_QUOTES](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-mode/#ansi_quotes). Are you by chance trying to load SQL code generated for another DB engine such as Oracle or PostgreSQL? That will normally not work, each engine has its own data types and SQL dialect.